# How to update Azure Device Twin desired and reported properties

Tags: python, azure, api

I am having a JSON payload which I want to pass to the Azure device twin with the help of API and python script integration. The sample payload is as follows:

```
para1 = {"time": [0,23,30]}
para2 = {"site":"test"}
```

I want to pass this data to the device twin, so that even if the device is offline, as soon as it comes online the information will be updated. Please help me achieve this flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass some params to [Azure IOT device twin Desired properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#device-twins), so that your device could receive it later, try the code below :

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from azure.iot.hub import IoTHubRegistryManager
from azure.iot.hub.models import Twin, TwinProperties

IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING = ""
DEVICE_ID = ""


iothub_registry_manager = IoTHubRegistryManager(IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING)

desired = {
    "para1" : {"time": [0,23,30]},
    "para2" : {"site":"test"}
}

twin = iothub_registry_manager.get_twin(DEVICE_ID)

twin_patch = Twin(properties= TwinProperties(desired=desired))

iothub_registry_manager.update_twin(DEVICE_ID, twin_patch, twin.etag)
```

Result:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
Seems there is something wrong with your connection string, you can find it here:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried this script but I am getting error. I've updated it in the question. Please check

Comment: @vishruti,Seems there is something wrong with your IOTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Stanley, can you please check this link and help me through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66702550/how-to-send-dynamic-reported-properties-for-device-twin-using-python

Comment: is that possible to patch reported properties as well?
i tried...

getting this:

in update_twin
    raise HttpOperationError(self._deserialize, response)
msrest.exceptions.HttpOperationError: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Bad Request'