# How to send dynamic reported properties for Device twin using Python

Tags: python, azure-iot-hub

I want to regularly update the desired properties for IoT Device. The desired properties that I am sending is as follows:

```
desired = {
    "para1" : {"time": [11,22,33]},
    "para2" : {"site":"demo.com"}
}
```

Following is the script running inside the device, as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-twin-getstarted) documentation

```
import time
import threading
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubModuleClient

CONNECTION_STRING = "IOTHUB Device Connection String"


def twin_update_listener(client):
    while True:
        patch = client.receive_twin_desired_properties_patch()  # blocking call
        print("Twin patch received:")
        print(patch)

def iothub_client_init():
    client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
    return client

def iothub_client_sample_run():
    try:
        client = iothub_client_init()

        twin_update_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=twin_update_listener, args=(client,))
        twin_update_listener_thread.daemon = True
        twin_update_listener_thread.start()

        # Send reported
        print ( "Sending data as reported property..." )
        reported_patch = {"connectivity": "cellular"}
        client.patch_twin_reported_properties(reported_patch)
        print ( "Reported properties updated" )

        while True:
            time.sleep(1000000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoT Hub Device Twin device sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ( "Starting the Python IoT Hub Device Twin device sample..." )
    print ( "IoTHubModuleClient waiting for commands, press Ctrl-C to exit" )
    iothub_client_sample_run()
```

Here it's updating reported_properties as a static value`(reported_patch = {"connectivity": "cellular"})`, but instead of this I want to upload the reported values same like the desired value:

```
{
        "para1" : {"time": [11,22,33]},
        "para2" : {"site":"demo.com"}
    }
```

Please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: So you want to upload reported_properties with the same value as desired value whcih uploaded previously?

Comment: yes, I want reported values to have exactly same data as desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, upload `desired` value to `reported` once `desired` value changes :

```
import time
import threading
from azure.iot.device import IoTHubModuleClient

CONNECTION_STRING = ""


def twin_update_listener(client):
    while True:
        patch = client.receive_twin_desired_properties_patch()  # blocking call
        print("Twin patch received")
        
        patch.pop('$version',None)
        print ( "Sending Twin as reported property..." )
        print(patch)
        client.patch_twin_reported_properties(patch)
        print ( "Reported properties updated" )
        

def iothub_client_init():
    client = IoTHubModuleClient.create_from_connection_string(CONNECTION_STRING)
    return client

def iothub_client_sample_run():
    try:
        client = iothub_client_init()

        twin_update_listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=twin_update_listener, args=(client,))
        twin_update_listener_thread.daemon = True
        twin_update_listener_thread.start()      
       
        while True:
            time.sleep(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ( "IoT Hub Device Twin device sample stopped" )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ( "Starting the Python IoT Hub Device Twin device sample..." )
    print ( "IoTHubModuleClient waiting for commands, press Ctrl-C to exit" )
    iothub_client_sample_run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stanley, it's working fine now.

Comment: @vishruti,glad to help :)